# How to get scope variable dynamically in angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I am using same directive (checkStrength) in different templates.
e.g

```
<ul id="strength" check-strength="pwdInfo.CurrentPassword"></ul>
<ul id="strength" check-strength="userInfo.CurrentPassword"></ul>
```

and i am assigning scope variable name in templates with this directive.
for this directive i am using watch as well.
e.g

```
scope.$watch(iAttrs.checkStrength, function () {
    dynamicVariable = iAttrs.checkStrength;
    ....
    ....
});
```

Now the value of "iAttrs.checkStrength" is stored in "dynamicVariable" and i want to get scope variable through this variable.

so i can use this directive at any where.

Comment: Why do you want scope variable here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get current scope of the variable do following steps:

**Step 1:** Inspect that element on which you binded the scope variable( *Right -> click -> click on Inspect element*)

**Step 2:** Goto console and type `angular.element($0).scope()` you will get current scope of the variable and all information related to it.